# Is pybind11 `py::array` object thread-safe?

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, pybind11, gil

With the `<thread>` library, I have written a multithreading piece of code in C++ which is called by Python, and I used the `pybind11` library. The code fails and throws `SIGSEGV` errors, however, I don't explicitly write any shared resource.

Inside the code I am using both `py::array`s objects, in particular, two views of a `py::array` previously stored in the C++ class. `py::array` keeps a reference to a `handle` object which does not perform any reference counting so I guess it is safe to work with it on multiple threads. Am I right?

Below a simple example to better clarify things:

```
MyClass::MyClass(py::array ar) {
    /* perform a reshape of ar */
    this->ar = ar;
}

MyClass::MyMethod() {
    py::gil_scoped_release release;
    /* create threads*/
    /* for each thread, compute two views of ar, ar1 and ar2*/
    /* compute a double using ar1 and ar2 */
    /* use double to update another structure (not py::array)*/
    /* join threads*/
    py::gil_scoped_acquire acquire;
    return 
}
```

Finally, note that the structure I update is just a pointer extracted from a `py::buffer_info` object and I take care to update separate parts in each thread.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but no, the array familly of object is apparently not thread safe.

When I work with pybind11 arrays and openMP I always extract the data pointers (
with the data() and mutableData() functions), the shape and the strides out of the parallels regions and uses the data pointer within the parallel regions.